# Styling Pull to Refresh Nativescript Angular

Tags: angular, nativescript, pull-to-refresh

I'm following along to the Nativescript Angular Pull to Refresh Styling demo ([Found here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/blob/b5af933ffec3bfb6a8140ee9965589f08938f753/listview/src/app/examples/pull-to-refresh/customize/listview-pull-to-refresh-customize.component.ts)) and can't get `this.myListViewComponent` to not be `undefined` and thus this snippet never gets triggered:

```
if (this.myListViewComponent && this.myListViewComponent.listView) {
  let style = new PullToRefreshStyle();
  style.indicatorColor = new Color("red");
  style.indicatorBackgroundColor = new Color("blue");
  this.myListViewComponent.listView.pullToRefreshStyle = style;
}
```

Really the only difference here is that it's part of the home page, which is being lazy loaded (I'm not sure that matters).

Is there another way to style the PullToRefresh indicator?

The following snippet comes from the Nativescript Core documentation so it doesn't apply to Angular:

```
<lv:RadListView.pullToRefreshStyle>
    <lv:PullToRefreshStyle
        indicatorColor="white" 
        indicatorBackgroundColor="blue"/>
</lv:RadListView.pullToRefreshStyle>
```

Obviously the following example doesn't work for the Angular code.  Is there another way I'm missing like this totally fake, pseudo-code:

```
<RadListView>
    <ng-template>...</ng-template>
    <PullToRefreshStyle
        indicatorColor="white" 
        indicatorBackgroundColor="blue">
    </PullToRefreshStyle>
</RadListView>
```

I'm using Nativescript 6+.

Comment: Can you share a Playground sample of what you tried to demonstrate the `undefined` issue you mentioned.

Comment: Hi Monaj, the link has the code I used.  I'm using the sample exactly as is.  Do you know of a way to use "PullToRefreshStyle" in the HTML rather than in the .ts file?

Comment: Would this have to do with Angular 8?  I do have an *if condition.  The {N} source code puts the code in `ngOnInt` but the Angular docs say to put it inside of `ngAfterViewInit`.  When I do that, well, nothing seems to happen.  lol

Comment: I would recommend using `loaded` event to gain access to component immediately, but without a Playground sample I can't say much.

Comment: Thanks Manoj!  Is there a link where I can see an example of a `loaded` event.

Comment: Also, is there an HTML version?  I'd rather not use typescript to set this.  It's easier for me to use `indicatorBackgroundColor` with `PullToRefreshStyle` as a property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`loaded` event is handled just like any other event you may use in Angular.

**HTML**

```
<RadListView class="list-group" pullToRefresh="true" [items]="countries"
    (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)" (loaded)="onLoaded($event)">
    ....
</RadListView>
```

**TS**

```
onLoaded(event: EventData) {
    let style = new PullToRefreshStyle();
    style.indicatorColor = new Color("red");
    style.indicatorBackgroundColor = new Color("blue");
    (<RadListView>event.object).pullToRefreshStyle = style;
}
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=9gQyzq)

Comment: Woo!  Thank you, Manoj!

Comment: How can I trigger a method via pullToRefresh?

Comment: If I understood your question right, you already have `pullToRefreshInitiated` event to which you may assign a callback.

Comment: Hi its working, but after done the pull to refresh list is not going to original position.some gap is there